# Is there a limit to the amount of directories I can add to PATH

Tags: command-line, path, environment-variables

I've run into an issue recently where adding a new PATH variable deletes the previous one added. However, I need to add both of these variables to PATH in order to run a python wrapper I'm working on from command line. Does this mean there is a limit to the number of variables I can add to path? And can I delete some path variables I no longer use?

For reference, I'm running Windows 10 and have been adding variables to path by going through from Control Panel to Advanced System Settings and then going from there to Environment Variables. There you can add to your PATH variable by clicking new.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us how you are adding new variables to PATH.

Comment: Updated, would you like me to post actual screenshots of me editing my Environment Variables?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that one way to circumvent this is to add multiple directories to PATH at once, separating them with semicolons. For example,

Variable Name = PATH

Variable Value = C:\path\to\directory1;C:\path\to\directory2\;C:\path\to\directory3

Comment: Yes, PATH has usually all directories you need as default. You may add/remove as you wish. You also did't state if you are using Windows/Linux etc.

Comment: If this worked for you, just accept your own answer.